# Tumblr follow/dashboard button now showing?

Tags: css, animation, tumblr

After adding the following code under `<style>` to my theme on Tumblr

```
.tail {
position:fixed;
bottom:0px;
right:0px;
margin-bottom:434px;
margin-right:53px;
width: 61px;
height: 168px;
background: url(http://static.tumblr.com/hp60lp8/Nkpn9k0se/tail.png); 
-webkit-animation: swing 5s infinite; 
-webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
animation: swing 5s infinite;
animation-play-state: paused;
}

.tail:hover {
-webkit-animation-play-state:running;
-webkit-animation: swing 5s;
}


@-webkit-keyframes swing {
20% {
-webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 15deg);
transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 15deg);
}

40% {
-webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, -50deg);
transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, -50deg);
 }

 60% {
-webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 12deg);
transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 12.5deg);
 }

80% {
-webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, -12deg);
transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, -12.5deg);
 }

100% {
-webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 0deg);
transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 0deg);
    }
}
```

and this one after `<body>`

```
<div class="tail"></div>
```

My Tumblr follow/dashboard/customize buttons have vanished. The odd thing is that [the links are there](http://coralines.co.vu/), you can tell when you hover in the upper right corner, but the buttons are gone. I've tried doing everything, looking on google and using the codes offered and putting them in after body, but all it gives me is **404 not found** (which makes me assume that the links they're using are old).

Is it possible that I've over edited my theme and just can't use the code above? Or is there a way to get them back?

Comment: disregard my previous comment, i can see the links now. wait

Comment: ohp. okay. disregarding and waiting.

Comment: do you want to remove the follow buttons completely?

Comment: no I want them back, the problem is that they disappeared when i put in the div class code. which is weird because the links remained.

Comment: I presume this was resolved as the buttons are now showing: http://i.imgur.com/1xbP9MD.png

Comment: @mikedidthis what browser are you using? I believe this is how the buttons should look like: http://i.imgur.com/RmVKTYM.png

Comment: @khakiout Chrome. The buttons change colour depending on the background of the site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**

For some reason, the animation is pushing or hiding the Follow buttons. One workaround is to remove the animation on the `.tail` rule but retain it on the `.tail:hover`. When the mouse hovers about the tail it will start to animate but the Follow buttons will be pushed out again. But once the mouse moves out from tail, the Follow buttons becomes visible again.

```
.tail {
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0px;
    right:0px;
    margin-bottom:432px;
    margin-right:50px;
    width: 61px;
    height: 168px;
    background: url(http://static.tumblr.com/hp60lp8/Nkpn9k0se/tail.png);
}
```

Also, you can add `@-moz-keyframes` rule so that the tail will move in Mozilla browsers as well. I also notice that the Follow buttons doesn't get pushed away in Mozilla.

Comment: that's because the regular @keyframe animation was deleted, easy fix. Is there any way I can have both the animation and my follow button? Or do I have to chose one or the other?

Comment: im sure there's a way to choose both of them. ill try out some things or workarounds